# How to access bamboo variables in C#

Tags: c#, environment-variables, bamboo, confluence

How do I access bamboo variables(Plan and Branch variables) in C#? In powershell, I can access using $env:bamboo_variableName. I'm not sure how can I do it in C#. These are my examples.

Bamboo variable name: vCheckoutJob

```
 var databaseServer = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("bamboo_vCheckoutJob"); //returns null
 var databaseServer = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("bamboo_vCheckoutJob", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine); // returns null
```

Comment: I've used `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TEMP")` a lot of times. Seems you have to check that `bamboo_vCheckoutJob` was set. You can set it manually (just to check) using `set bamboo_vCheckoutJob='test value"`. Please note that you have to set it in the same cmd session that is used to run the executable, (like Win+R, cmd, Enter, set bamboo_vCheckoutJob, run exe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it could be a good idea to do some error-handling.

Let's check that the user actually has set that specific environment variable we're looking for:

```
string bambooEnv;
bool delete_temp_env = false;

bambooEnv = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("bamboo_vCheckoutJob");
// Didn't exist, if necessary, create it temporarily.
if (bambooEnv == null) 
{
   Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("bamboo_vCheckoutJob", "your_value");
   delete_temp_env = true;

   // Now retrieve it.
   bambooEnv = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("bamboo_vCheckoutJob");
}

// If we've created it, now delete it.
if (delete_temp_env) { 
   Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("bamboo_vCheckoutJob", null);

   // Verify Deletion
   if (Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("bamboo_vCheckoutJob") == null)
      Console.WriteLine("EnvVar var has been deleted again");
}
```

Wrapped in a function:

```
public static string getEnvironmentVariable(string envVar, string fallbackValue)
{
    bool deleteTempEnv = false;
    string value = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(envVar);

    if (value == null)
    {
        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable(envVar, fallbackValue);
        deleteTempEnv = true;

        value = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(envVar);
    }

    if (deleteTempEnv)
    {
        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable(envVar, null);

        if (Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(envVar) == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("EnvVar has been deleted again");
        }
    }

    return value;
}
```

Usage:

```
var databaseServer = getEnvironmentVariable("bamboo_vCheckoutJob", "default_path_to_server");
```

> What's happening?
>
> We're checking if the environment variable is set, if it is, return it.
>
> *If not*
>
> Let's create the environment variable with a default value.
>   If we had to create the environment variable ourselves, *lets not* keep it in the users system while the program isn't running and delete it again.